# Speed and the MapThread function

Tags: performance-tuning, map

Can anyone help explain why MapThread is so slow in this simple case?

```
p = 0.1;
t = Table[1, {10^6}];
SeedRandom[1000];
AbsoluteTiming[a = Map[# RandomChoice[{p, 1 - p} -> {1, 0}] &, t];]
SeedRandom[1000];
AbsoluteTiming[b = MapThread[# RandomChoice[{p, 1 - p} -> {1, 0}] &, {t}];]
Norm[a-b]
```

outputs

```
{0.555723, Null}
{3.696282, Null}
0
```

Comment: `MapThread` unpacks the array... and does more work under the covers (what would you expect re: latter?), and I'd venture compilation (auto) behaves differently.

Comment: In V10.1 on OS X, I'm getting the same time, ~3.7 sec, with both `Map` and `MapThread`. Can anyone confirm this? `PackArrayQ` returns `False` for both `a` and `b`.

Comment: @m_goldberg I'm used 10.1 on OS X to write my answer. What happens if you run the code in Oleksandr's answer?

Comment: @Pickett. From the compiled function `f`` I get timings comparable to what he got. The returned array is packed.

Comment: @m_goldberg Strange. And your "MapCompileLength" is set to 100? This is confirmed?

Comment: @Pickett. Yes. `"MapCompileLength" -> 100`. Not only that, but `Map[# + RandomInteger[] &, t]` produces a packed array and runs much quicker than `MapThread[# + RandomInteger[] &, {t}]` which does not. In this case, the `Map` is being compiled.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is because of the compilation that kicks in automatically if the list in `Map` exceeds a certain number of elements.

```
"MapCompileLength" /. ("CompileOptions" /. SystemOptions["CompileOptions"])
(* Out: 100 *)
```

shows that the default setting is that if the list contains more than 100 elements then `Map` will be compiled. `MapThread` on the other hand does not seem to use automatic compilation.

This piece of code will test our hypothesis. Don't forget to reset the setting or restart the kernel once you're done:

```
SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> "MapCompileLength" -> Infinity]

p = 0.1;
t = Table[1, {10^6}];
SeedRandom[1000];
AbsoluteTiming[a = Map[# RandomChoice[{p, 1 - p} -> {1, 0}] &, t];]
SeedRandom[1000];
AbsoluteTiming[
 b = MapThread[# RandomChoice[{p, 1 - p} -> {1, 0}] &, {t}];]
Norm[a - b]

(* Out: {3.57806, Null}, {3.66936, Null}, 0 *)
```

Comment: Thx for verifying comment , +1

Answer (score 12):

`Map` is automatically compiled. Yes, even with `RandomChoice`. Try it:

```
f = Compile[{{p, _Real, 0}, {t, _Integer, 1}}, 
  Map[# RandomChoice[{p, 1 - p} -> {1, 0}] &, t]
 ];
f // InputForm (* -> clean bytecode *)
```

Check its performance:

```
p = 0.1;
t = Table[1, {10^6}];
SeedRandom[1000];

AbsoluteTiming[a = Map[# RandomChoice[{p, 1 - p} -> {1, 0}] &,t];] (* -> 0.578125 seconds *)

AbsoluteTiming[c = f[0.1, t];] (* -> 0.593750 seconds *)
```

The timings are the same, so this is the solution. It's also the reason that `Map` doesn't unpack and `MapThread` does. (Compiled code only works with packed arrays.)

`MapThread` doesn't have this ability and uses the uncompiled code. `Map` will be the same if it is not allowed to compile, as [Pickett](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/731/pickett) shows in [his answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/86095/).

Comment: Pickett already said this, but I was already typing the answer when he posted his, so I thought I might as well post it. Maybe I'll delete it later though since I don't think it adds much to the question.

Comment: I think it's a great complement to my answer. +1